# How a REST client can parse huge JSON response in REST web services

Tags: java, json, rest

If a REST API is sending huge JSON (like 1000 fields) and if client is interested in only 10 fields. What will be the best way to parse the xml at client side?

Comment: Uhm. There is no XML in JSON, so there is nothing to parse

Answer (score 0):

If the server is using GraphQL, then the client can directly request the 10 fields.

Otherwise, you would use a streaming/JSON token parsing library rather than reading the entire response into memory

Answer (score 0):

If you have different subscribers to your API who need different set of data then GraphQL is your ultimate answer.

There are 2 ways of approaching the problem. You can tell your client that they can implement an abstraction layer, called backend for frontend (BFF), in their system. In this BFF, they can send necessary fields to their client-side application.

Another option; if you don't want to lose your client and you want to keep your REST API, your client can define what data fields they need via querystring and in your system you manage the complexity and return customized response.

```
api/{resource}/fields=name,email,zipcode
```